# Disable some product categories from Woocommerce category dropdown widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, custom-taxonomy

I'm searching for a solution to hide specific categories in the standard woocommerce category widget that is in the sidebar on the shop page, i'm using the dropdown.

I've searched but can seem to find it anywhere, tried en rebuild multiple scripts but cant seem to figure it out..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the following code where you will be able to disable some product category terms Ids defining them below in this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'widget_product_categories_disable_terms', 10, 1);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'widget_product_categories_disable_terms', 10, 1);
function widget_product_categories_disable_terms( $args ) {
    // Excluding coma separated term IDs from product category
    $args['exclude'] = array( 12, 18 ); 

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a bad solution, I mean not to complain about the above. But this isn't dynamic at all. By providing the above solution you won't be able to change the hidden categories unless you're a developer.

I'm not the author of this plugin but it seems to do what we want to do.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-categories-on-shop-page/